# Function to start and stopThread?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem with my program. When I start my program and press any key, it print "Sucefully". If I click button start one more time, and press any key, it will print "Sucefully" 2x, and so on. 3x 4x 5x.. how can I fix this problem? if i use join() my program will crash.

and, how can I stop Listener, since theres no stop() option.. ?

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener
from tkinter import *
import threading
from functools import partial

app = Tk()
def press(key):
    keyd = str(key)
    keyd = keyd.replace("Key.space", " ")
    keyd = keyd.replace("'", "")
    with open("doc.docx", "a") as o:
        o.write(keyd)
        print("Succefuly")
def startListener(arg):
    if arg == btStart:
        def subLis():
            with Listener(on_press=press) as l:
                l.join()
        thr = threading.Thread(target=subLis)
        thr.start()

btStart = Button(app, text="Start")
btStart.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
btStart["command"] = partial(startListener, btStart)

btStop = Button(app, text="Stop")
btStop.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
btStop["command"] = partial(startListener, btStop)

app.geometry("300x100+900+400")
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: create global variable `thr = None` so you could access it in every moment. And assing Thread to this variable only when `thr  is None`. When you stop Thread then assign `thr = None`. This way you know when thread is already running and you don't have to create new thread.

Comment: I don't know why you use `pynput` if you can use `app.bind('<Key>', press)`

Comment: as you can see in example in [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html#monitoring-the-keyboard) to stop `Listener` (and end thread)  `press` has to use `return False`

Comment: if i create a var thr=None at start of script.
it say "local variable 'thr' referenced before assignment"

Comment: it can't give this error. Some other line could give this error but I tried code with `thr = None` and I don't get this error.

Comment: you can get this error if you use `if thr is None` in function. You have to add `    `global thr` inside funtion to inform function that you want to use external variable `thr` instead of creating local one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you will keep thread in global variable then you can check if it exists and not create second thread.

At this moment I know only one method to stop thread - use some key combination to execute `return False` in `press`. It will stop `Listener` and it will end thread. In code key `ESC` stops thread.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, Key
from tkinter import *
import threading
from functools import partial

def press(key):
    keyd = str(key)
    keyd = keyd.replace("Key.space", " ")
    keyd = keyd.replace("'", "")

    with open("doc.docx", "a") as o:
        o.write(keyd)
        print("Succefuly", keyd)

    # stop Listener (and end thread)
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False

def subLis():
    with Listener(on_press=press) as l:
        l.join()

def startListener(arg):
    global thr # inform function to use external variable

    if arg == btStart:
        if thr is None:
            thr = threading.Thread(target=subLis)
            thr.start()
        else:
            print('already running')

    if arg == btStop:
        if thr is None:
            print('not running')
        else:
            print('TODO: stop thread')
            #thr = None

# ---------------------------------------------------------

thr = None

app = Tk()
app.geometry("300x100+900+400")

btStart = Button(app, text="Start")
btStart.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
btStart["command"] = partial(startListener, btStart)

btStop = Button(app, text="Stop")
btStop.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
btStop["command"] = partial(startListener, btStop)

app.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** I found in documentation that `Listener` iherits from `Thread` so you can use it in the same way as `Thread`

```
thr = Listener(...)
thr.start()
```

There is function `Listener.stop()` to stop listener. For this code it will be

```
thr.stop()
```

New code

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, Key
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial


def press(key):
    keyd = str(key)
    keyd = keyd.replace("Key.space", " ")
    keyd = keyd.replace("'", "")

    with open("doc.docx", "a") as o:
        o.write(keyd)
        print("key:", keyd)

    # key combination to stop listener (and end thread)
    #if key == Key.esc:
    #    return False


def startListener(arg):
    global thr # inform function to use external variable

    if arg == btStart:
        if thr is None:
            print('[+] starting listener')
            thr = Listener(on_press=press)
            thr.start()
        else:
            print('[!] already running')

    if arg == btStop:
        if thr is None:
            print('[!] not running')
        else:
            print('[+] stoping thread')
            thr.stop()
            thr.join()
            thr = None

# ---------------------------------------------------------

thr = None

app = Tk()
app.geometry("300x100+900+400")

btStart = Button(app, text="Start")
btStart.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
btStart["command"] = partial(startListener, btStart)

btStop = Button(app, text="Stop")
btStop.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
btStop["command"] = partial(startListener, btStop)

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: there is `Listener.stop()` and you can see it in code as `thr.stop()`